# Matlab - Issue calling java library

Tags: java, matlab, jar, classpath

I am trying to access classes from a java library within Matlab.

I am able to add the path to the dynamic javaclasspath:

```
> javaaddpath('path\myLibrary.lib.jar')
```

But cannot add any of the subfolders:

```
> javaaddpath('path\myLibrary.lib.jar.com')

Warning: Invalid file or directory 'path\myLibrary.lib.jar.com'
```

Nor classes:

```
> javaaddpath('path\myLibrary.lib.jar.com')

Warning: Invalid file or directory 'path\myLibrary.lib.jar.com.MyClass.class'
```

Nor construct javaObjects using the library.

Any ideas why this is or how I should go about doing this?

Comment: What do you expect `'path\myLibrary.lib.jar.com'` to be? Can you show us how you're trying to instantiate your java class after calling the first `javaaddpath` command?

Comment: what's the problem with using ``javaaddpath('path\myLibrary.lib.jar')`` since it's working?

Comment: in the 'Current Folder' panel in Matlab 'com' is shown as a sub-directory within 'path\myLibrary.lib.jar'

Comment: I am trying to replicate use of the library in another java project. The java code they use is : Item item1 = MyClass.eINSTANCE,createItem();